# How to extract all HEVC i-frame images from a x265 video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, decoding, hevc, libx265

I need to drop all the B-frames and P-frames, only keeping the I-frames to be saved as images.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: To my point of view, this is not surely an FFmepg command question. Potentially I was going to edit the source codes of FFmpeg to extract frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct the decoder to skip non-keyframes using `-skip_frame`.

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i input.mp4 -vsync vfr img%04d.png
```

Comment: ffmpeg questions are off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: ffmpeg Qs aren't off-topic. And this Q is not about "interactive use of the command line tool"

Comment: From the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic.